# How to check why .desktop file is not running?

Tags: .desktop, konqueror

I have a desktop file with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type = Service
Name = Konqueror
Exec = konqueror %U
Comment = KDE File Manager & Web Browser
Icon = konqueror
```

Upon launching it gives me this: 'Error loading the application'.
But it does not explain what the problem is.
So how can I open this file in terminal emulator to see the error message?

P.S. The 'konqueror' command in the terminal runs the browser with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

You take a .desktop file that you know is working, make a copy of it and replace one by one each line with the one from your konqueror.desktop file. After each change you test, whether it works. That way you find out which line *doesn't* work.

Did you try with an absolute path aka `Exec = /usr/bin/konqueror` or similar?

Comment: I tried just now, it doesn't work. But 'konqueror' executable is exactly there and when I double click it launches perfectly well!